# Android Cam Fatal Excpetion fileURIExposed

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
String caminhoFoto = getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/"+ System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg";
            File arquivoFoto = new File(caminhoFoto);
            intentImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(arquivoFoto));
```

I write this code, and the error is below, I already added the provider, no manifest and nothing, continues the error that is without any code, I was told that using the content

Erro:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: br.com.viniciusdeep.agenda, PID: 22038
              android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.viniciusdeep.agenda/files/1524003224785.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
```

Answer (score 1):

in Android 7.0, the file scheme on a Uri is banned, in effect. If you attempt
to pass a `file:` Uri in an Intent that is going to another app, you will crash with a `FileUriExposedException` exception.

you will face similar issues with putting file: Uri values on the clipboard in `ClipData`

This is coming from an updated edition of StrictMode.
`StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder` has a `penaltyDeathOnFileUriExposure()` method
that triggers the detection of file: Uri values and the resulting
`FileUriExposedException` exceptions. And, it appears that this is pre-configured,
much as how StrictMode is pre-configured to apply `penaltyDeathOnNetwork()` (the
source of your `NetworkOnMainThreadException` crashes).

However, this only kicks in if your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 24 or higher. At that
point, you will need to find other ways of getting your content to other apps, such as
via a class called `FileProvider` Or, you can also
disable the check by configuring your own `StrictMode.VmPolicy` and skipping
`directFileUriExposure()`, though this is not a great solution.

Comment: "Pavneet_Singh, I tried to do the way you said it, and nothing changed, can you tell me how it would look ?, I did as you said." - Vincius Mangueira

Comment: @MarcelHofgesang use `FileProvider` i sent you two resources you can find more by googling "sharing file with fileprovider" hope these helps:  https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-use-android-fileprovider-to-share-files-between-apps/      https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/share-files-using-fileprovider